# Remove various elements by position

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am doing an exercise for class which after a while racking my brains I found the theory way to do it but can't figure out the way to do in Haskell.
The exercise being:

> Having a list `xs` with `n` different elements. The combination of the `n` elements of the list `xs` taking them from `m` to `m` (with `m <= n`) are all the possible sets of `m` elements (with no repetitions) that can be formed from the original `n` elements.
>
> The order of the elements does not have importance (meaning that `"abc"` is considered the same combination as `"bca"`).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> comb 0 "abcd" -> [""]
> comb 3 "bcd" -> ["bcd"]
> comb 2 "bcd" -> ["cd","bd","bc"]
> comb 3 "abcd" -> ["bcd", "acd", "abd", "abc"]
> ```
>
> Define a function `comb` that takes a natural number `m` and a list `xs` with `n` different elements.

The only way I could find is that I need a value that will my "position pointer" `pp`, that way it will remove `length xs - m` elements after that pointer and then in the recursive call do `m + pp`, so it "jumps" to the next position. I will write an example in a kind of pseudo-Haskell way:

```
m = 3   xs = "abcd"   * = pp

*abcd       *remove (length xs - m) after pointer
Solution:  "bcd"  

*Recursively jump pointer by (length xs - m):

"a*bcd"   ->   "acd"
"ab*cd"   ->   "abd"
"abc*d"   ->   "abc"
"abcd*"   ->   [""]
```

I am really sorry of this kind of invention, I tried to use the pointer analogy because I think it is quite easy to see it that way, and I used I kind of mix of pseudo code and Haskell because do not know how to do it another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to pick `n` elements from a list?

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

If `n` is zero, no matter what the list is, you have a single pick with no elements in it.

```
comb 0 _ = [[]]
```

Otherwise, if your list is empty, you have no picks at all. (Note how this is different from the above.)

```
comb _ [] = []
```

Otherwise, your list has a head and a tail. The picks are as follows. First, you have all the picks that include the head, and then all the picks that exclude the head.

```
comb n (x:xs) = withHead ++ withoutHead where
```

How to build all the picks that exclude the head? That's easy, just apply the function recursively to the tail of the list.

```
    withoutHead = comb n xs
```

What about the picks that include the head? That's also easy, just apply the function recursively to the tail of the list, but this time make the picks one element shorter. Then slap the head in front of each pick.

```
    withHead = map (x:) (comb (n-1) xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially what you can do is each time pick an element and just keep adding elements.

To prevent *symmetry* we can say that if we pick a character at position *i*, we can only pick items at the right side of position *i*, so it means that we pass as recursion the *rest* of the characters in the list.

We can first construct a helper function that for a given list `[a]`, returns a list of 2-tuples `[(a, [a])]` with the item picked and the rest of the items, so:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick [] = []
pick (x : xs) = … : …
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise. For `[1,4,2,5]`, it thus should return `[(1, [4,2,5]), (4, [2,5]), (2, [5]), (5, [])]`, since we can pick any of the elements, and each time have a list of remaining elements at the right side of the one we picked we can use to pick other items.

Now that we have that, we can make a recursive function to pick *n* elements. We do this by checking how many items we still have to pick. For no items we return a single item: the empty list. For *n* items we pick an item and recurse with *n-1* items:

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb n xs = [x : zs | (x, ys) <- pick xs, zs <- comb (n - 1) ys]
```

We can boost this further to only pick elements where there are still *n-1* elements left after picking. I leave that as an exercise as well.

We here thus *don't* need the length of the list(s), we can just pick elements. This will even produce results if the initial list has infinite length: if we need *m* items, it will eventually return *[x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, …, x<sub>m-1</sub>, x<sub>n</sub>]* for any *n ≥ m*, and thus produce results, although it will never produce a result that starts with *[x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, …]* for the above implementation.